# Detecting getopts `--` (double dash) to issue a message

Tags: bash, arguments, getopts

I am using the customary way of using `getopts` through a variable named `arg`.  I can capture the option names as follows.  Is it possible to detect the moment getopts reaches "--" so that I can issue a message?

```
while getopts "$shortopts" arg; do
   echo "--> arg: $arg"
   case $arg in
   ("V")
     printf '%s\n' "Version" 
     return
     ;;
   ("u")
     printf '%s\n' "Usage" 
     return
     ;;
   ("h")
     printf '%s\n' "Help" 
     return
     ;;
   esac
done
```

Comment: Your code contains an unterminated `while` loop and several unexplained `return` statements. I'm not sure why you are including this code fragment at all as it doesn't seem to be code that you are actually using.

Comment: It is not very important, what is important in how to capture the encounter `"--"` rather than the usual options.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Is it possible to detect the moment getopts reaches "--" so that I can issue a message?

You shouldn't need to.

`getopts` implements the standard option processing, which means that it stops looking for options when it either sees an argument that's not an option, or if it sees the argument `--`, which explicitly terminates the list of options. (That first point is different from the GNU custom which looks for options on the whole command line.)

There's no need for the program to care about meeting `--`.

That said, since `getopts` doesn't trash the list of positional parameters, you could peek in there to see if the last argument was `--`.

```
#!/bin/bash
while getopts a:bc opt; do
    echo "option $opt arg $OPTARG"
done
last=
if [ "$OPTIND" -ge 2 ]; then
        shift "$((OPTIND - 2))"
        last=$1
        shift 1
else
        shift "$((OPTIND - 1))"
fi
if [ "$last" = "--" ]; then
        echo "options were terminated by a double-dash (or last arg was an option-argument '--')"
fi
echo "remaining args: $*"
```

That would give e.g.

```
$ bash opts.sh -a blah -- -b foo
option a arg blah
options were terminated by a double-dash (or last arg was an option-argument '--')
remaining args: -b foo
```

but since it only looks at the last argument, it could be either the `--` separator, or `--` as an option-argument to some option. E.g. this is the false positive, the `--` is not the separator here:

```
$ bash opts.sh -a -- foo
option a arg --
options were terminated by a double-dash (or last arg was an option-argument '--')
remaining args: foo
```

Of course you could also implement your own option processing, but it's a bit annoying to do since the shell makes it awkward to process substrings. (You need to recognize `-abc` as three different options, or as one, or as two, depending on if `-a` or `-b` take an option-argument.)

In any case, unless you're doing something far more complex than usually needed, there shouldn't be any reason to look at `--`. Even if you do something more complex, you might consider doing it outside `getopts` (and with another separator), similarly to how the expression in `find` is given, or how GNU parallel takes lists of arguments separated by `:::`, `::::` etc.

Comment: I very much appreciate your analysis.  Your comments should suffice in regards to my question.

Comment: Could you explain what is meant by `-- as an option-argument`?  Is there any practical use of `--` besides separating options from non-options?

Comment: @Alta, what I mean is that if you have something like `getopts a:bc`, then the option `-a` takes an argument as part of the option syntax. If you have `-a foo` on the command line, getopts returns `a` in the named variable, and then `foo` in `OPTARG`. Now the argument to the option `-a`, the option-argument, could well be `--`, because it can be an arbitrary string. You could run `grep -e -- file1 file2` to look for the string `--`. And in general you could have an option like `-f <filename>`, where someone might want to give the filename `--` (it's a valid filename, after all).

Comment: (With grep, there's also the option of running `grep -- -- file1 file2`, where the first `--` is the separator and the second is the first of the remaining command line args, and used as the pattern if `-e` wasn't used. Looks a bit confusing, right?)

Comment: The terminology here is a bit confusing, since everything that comes from the command line is an "argument" to the process invocation. But then we have the options, which might take arguments themselves, so those are option-arguments. In `grep -e foo file1`, all the three words (after `grep`) are command line args, but `-e` is also an option, `foo` also an option-argument (to `-e`), and `file1` a non-option argument.

Comment: I got to understand now.  Many thanks.

Comment: (... and you could also have e.g. `grep -e -- -- --`, where the first is an opt-arg to `-e` (the pattern to look for), the second is the separator, and the last is the first non-option arg, giving a filename. That would look for the string `--` in the file `--`.)

Answer (score 5):

After looping `getopts` it is custom to do:

```
shift "$((OPTIND - 1))"
```

the rest of the arguments will then be the ones left.  (see for example EXAMPLE¹ section of `man getopts` 1POSIX).

Point being, [from DESCRIPTION](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2018edition/utilities/getopts.html):

> Any of the following shall identify the end of options: the first "--" argument that is not an option-argument, finding an argument that is not an option-argument and does not begin with a '-', or encountering an error.

---

Say you have pattern `ab:`, then (here 4. demonstrating `--`):

1. `-a x y z`

   - `-a` flag. Rest: `x y z`
2. `-a -b foo x y z`

   - `-a` flag + `-b` value = `foo`. Rest: `x y z`
3. `-b foo -a -b bar x y z`

   - `-a` flag + `-b` value = `foo` and `bar`. Rest: `x y z`
   - Both values for `-b` are passed. Up to the script how to handle.
4. `-a -b foo -- -a -b x y z`

   - `-a` flag + `-b` value = `foo`. Rest: `-a -b x y z`
5. `-a -b foo -x y z`

   - Error / unknown option `-x`
6. `-b foo bar -x y z`

   - `-b` value = `foo`. Rest: `bar -x y z`
7. `-b -- -a bar -x y z`

   - `-a` flag + `-b` value = `--`. Rest: `bar -x y z`

As for 7, note that as an argument for an option can have any string including `--`, or `""` for that matter.

---

<sup>¹ though note how that example is missing the quotes around the `$((...))`; POSIX examples do assume `$IFS` contains its default value, which is unfortunate as they can't be used in any context.</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Condition your `getopts` loop on a variable initialized to 0, set it to 1 in the `"--")` case. E.g.

```
stop=0
...
while [[ 0 -eq $stop ]] ; do
# getopts call ...
...
"--") stop=1;;r
esac
done
```

Comment: How would I be able to trigger entry in `--` ?  Currently I am using `myfunc -v 3 -g -- john andrew`. Using `while getopts "$shortopts" arg; do` never gets `arg` to return `--`.

Comment: @Alta, you don't, `getopts` deals with it itself.

Comment: @Alta If that is your issue, it should be part of the question. It's unclear what "handle" in the question means.

Comment: @ilkkachu Basically, using  `while getopts "$shortopts" arg; do` never gets `arg` to be `"--"`?  There is no other mechanism in `getopts` that detects `"--"` ?